# Set GoogleMaps inside Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a FragmentActivity with a lateral bar (like a menu bar), and a container to put fragments there. 
From this FragmentActivity I call to other fragments using `onClickListener` of each button (from the lateral bar).

So for example, FragmentActivity is called `MenuViewActivity`. This calls `Navigation` fragment and sets it's layout on the container.

In `Navigation` Fragment, I have a button that starts `GoogleMaps` (*or that is what I need to get*)

**[MenuViewActivity(FragmentActivity)]  >> [NavigationFragment(Fragment)] >> [GoogleMapsFragment(Fragment)**]

The idea is to fit the GoogleMaps windows in the same container that I set the other Fragments (like navigationFragment)

This is the code of **NavigationFragment.java**:

```
public class NavigationFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /**Inflate the layout for this fragment*/
    View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navegacion, container, false);

    mapBtn = (ImageView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.mapsButton);
    navBtn = (ImageView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.navigatorButton);

    mapBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    navBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    return mainView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.mapsButton:
            GoogleMapsFragment fragment_maps = new GoogleMapsFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment_maps).commit();
            break;
    }
}
```

This is the code of **GoogleMapsFragment.java**:

```
public class GoogleMapsFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /**Inflate the layout for this fragment*/
    View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.google_maps, container, false);

    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)  getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mMap = fm.getMap();

    return mainView;
}
```

And the code of the **google_maps.xml**:

```
<fragment 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
map:cameraTilt="45"
map:cameraZoom="14"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

I think that I'm not calling right the *GoogleMapsFragment* on the *onClick*, or that I cannot call maybe to the *fragment_container* from other fragment like I do in *NavigationFragment* because this id belongs to the layout of *MenuViewActivity*.

The logCat output's this:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class fragment
    at com.example.GoogleMapsFragment.onCreateView(GoogleMapsFragment.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's 
    AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Exception` is telling you exactly what the problem is. Since the last update of the google-play-services_lib you need to add the following to the AndroidManifest.xml within the application tag:

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Also, you have:

> android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
>   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

You should only have one of this attributes. Here you have two and they are pointing to two different classes. If you want backwards compatibility you should use `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`.

One suggestion. If you only need to display a map why not `extends` `SupportMapFragment` or `MapFragment` instead of `Fragment`?

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be main problem... but something tells me that the way I call GoogleMapsFragment on the onClick isn't the correct way

Comment: I've added that to manifest but shoes same logcat. I think that metadata should go inside activity declaration. But as using fragments, these aren't declared on manifest and had to put metadata outside aplication

Comment: my map-activity doesnt contain any meta-data though. The only meta-data i am using is for handling the gMaps-v2-key; and this one belongs to the application-tag :)

Comment: @bofredo I have the same definition for metadata in the manifest belonging to the aplication-tag (.maps.v2.API_KEY). Could you post an answer showing your code?

Comment: @Emmanuel I didn't know i could extend SupportMapFragment. I'l try with that and changing the declarations on the xml

Comment: I modyfied all theses things but continues with same error. Have a look at the onClick method, I'm not sure if this is called right this way, cause I'm calling the `fragment_container` but this id isn't in the fragment's inflated layout, it belongs to father fragment's layout